# how to generate config file for aws-nuke

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to delete all resources in my aws account, but the directions for aws-nuke says I need to create a config file:

```
At first you need to create a configfile for aws-nuke. This is a minimal one:

regions:
- eu-west-1
- global

account-blacklist:
- "999999999999" # production

accounts:
  "000000000000": {} # aws-nuke-example
With this config we can run aws-nuke:
```

My question is, how do I create this config file that deletes everything associated with an account and leaves me with a blank account?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely nuke everything associated with an account you just have to replace the zeros for the account number you want to erase like in your example. The {} means all resources types. Save the file as.YAML format and next issue the command like this:
`aws-nuke -c config/example.yaml --profile demo`

Check my example `config/example.yaml` file here:

```
regions:
#Regions where the resources are
  - "global"
  - "eu-central-1"
  - "eu-west-1"
  - "eu-west-2"
  - "eu-east-1"
  - "eu-east-2"
  - "us-east-1"
  - "us-east-2"
  - "us-west-1"
  - "us-west-2"
account-blocklist:
#Accounts you dont want to change
- 123456789101 # e.g production account 

resource-types: #not mandatory
  targets:
  # Specific resources you want to remove 
  - S3Object
  - S3Bucket
  - EC2Volume
  
  excludes: #not mandatory
  # Specific resources you don't want to remove
  - IAMUser

accounts:
  943725333913: {}
  # the {} means all resources associated with this account
  # instead you can use filters like this:
  943725333913:
        filters:
          S3Bucket:
          - "s3://my-bucket"
          S3Object:
          - type: "glob"
            value: "s3://my-bucket/*"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).